# How to avoid un-coalesced accesses in matrix multiplication CUDA kernel?

Tags: parallel-processing, cuda

I am learning CUDA with the book '**Programming Massively Parallel Processors**'. A practice problem from chapter 5 confuses me:

> For tiled matrix multiplication out of possible range of values for
>   BLOCK_SIZE, for what values of BLOCK_SIZE will the kernel completely
>   avoid un-coalesced accesses to global memory? (you only need to consider square blocks)

On my understanding, BLOCK_SIZE does little to memory-coalescing. As long as threads within single warp access consecutive elements, we will have a coalesced accesses. I could not figure out where the kernel has un-coalesced accesses to global memory. Any hints from you guys?

Here is the kernel's source codes:

```
#define COMMON_WIDTH 512
#define ROW_LEFT 500 
#define COL_RIGHT 250
#define K 1000
#define TILE_WIDTH 32
__device__ int D_ROW_LEFT = ROW_LEFT;
__device__ int D_COL_RIGHT = COL_RIGHT;
__device__ int D_K = K;
.....
__global__
void MatrixMatrixMultTiled(float *matrixLeft, float *matrixRight, float *output){
    __shared__  float sMatrixLeft[TILE_WIDTH][TILE_WIDTH];
    __shared__  float sMatrixRight[TILE_WIDTH][TILE_WIDTH];  
   int bx = blockIdx.x; int by = blockIdx.y;
   int tx = threadIdx.x; int ty = threadIdx.y;
   int col = bx * TILE_WIDTH + tx;
   int row = by * TILE_WIDTH + ty;
   float value = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < ceil(D_K/(float)TILE_WIDTH); ++i){
       if (row < D_ROW_LEFT && row * D_K + i * TILE_WIDTH  +tx < D_K){
        sMatrixLeft[ty][tx]  = matrixLeft[row * D_K + i * TILE_WIDTH  +tx];
       }
       if (col < D_COL_RIGHT && (ty + i * TILE_WIDTH) * D_COL_RIGHT  + col < D_K ){
        sMatrixRight[ty][tx] = matrixRight[(ty + i * TILE_WIDTH) * D_COL_RIGHT  + col];
       }
       __syncthreads();
       for (int j = 0; j < TILE_WIDTH; j++){
           value += sMatrixLeft[ty][j] * sMatrixRight[j][tx]; 
       }
       __syncthreads();
   }
   if (row < D_ROW_LEFT && col < D_COL_RIGHT ){
        output[row * D_COL_RIGHT + col] = value;
       }
}
```

Comment: I would guess they mean TILE_WIDTH, not block size, That is a *very* old book and I wouldn't recommend it as a first guide. Hardware and software have evolved considerably since that book was written almost 10 years ago

Comment: @talonmies  Thank you for your response. I think Robert Crovella clears my thought. Right now, I have the 3rd edition of the book 'Programming Massively Parallel Processors' published in 2016. Is it too old to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is incomplete, since the code you have posted does not make any reference to `BLOCK_SIZE`, and that is certainly at least very relevant to the question posed in the book.  More generally, questions that pose a kernel without the launch configuration are often incomplete, since the launch configuration is often relevant to both the correctness and the behavior, of a kernel.

I've not re-read this portion of the book right at the moment.  However I'll assume the kernel launch configuration includes a block dimension that is something like the following: (this information is absent from your question but should have been included, in my opinion, for a sensible question)

```
dim3 dimBlock(BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE);
dim3 dimGrid(...,...);
```

And I will assume the kernel launch is given by something like:

```
MatrixMatrixMultTiled<<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>>(...);
```

Your statement: "As long as threads within single warp access consecutive elements, we will have a coalesced accesses." is a reasonable working definition.  Let's show that that is violated for some choices of `BLOCK_SIZE`, given the above assumptions to cover over the gaps in your incomplete question.

Coalesced access is a term that applies to global memory accesses only.  We will therefore ignore accesses to shared memory.  We will also, for this discussion, ignore accesses to the `__device__` variables such as `D_ROW_LEFT`. (The access to those variables appears to be *uniform*.  We can quibble about whether that constitutes coalesced access.  My claim would be that it does constitute coalesced access, but we need not unpack that here.)  Therefore we are left with just 3 "access" points:

```
matrixLeft[row * D_K + i * TILE_WIDTH  +tx];
matrixRight[(ty + i * TILE_WIDTH) * D_COL_RIGHT  + col];
output[row * D_COL_RIGHT + col]
```

Now, to pick an example, let's suppose `BLOCK_SIZE` is 16.  Will any of the above access points violate your statement "threads within single warp access consecutive elements"?

Let's start with the block (0,0).  Therefore `row` is equal to `threadIdx.y` and `col` is equal to `threadIdx.x`.  Let's consider the first warp in that block.  Therefore the first 16 threads in that warp will have a `threadIdx.y` value of 0, and their `threadIdx.x` values will be increasing from 0..15.  Likewise the second 16 threads  in that warp will have a `threadIdx.y` value of 1, and their `threadIdx.x` values will be increasing from 0..15.

Now let's compute the actual index generated for the first access point above, across the warp.  Let's assume we are on the first loop iteration, so `i` is zero.  Therefore this:

```
matrixLeft[row * D_K + i * TILE_WIDTH  +tx];
```

reduces to:

```
matrixLeft[threadIdx.y * D_K + threadIdx.x];
```

`D_K` here is just the device copy of the `K` variable, which is 1000.  Now let's evaluate the reduced index expression above across our selected warp (0) in our selected block (0,0):

```
warp lane:    0  1  2  3  4  5  6  .. 15     16   17   18 .. 31
threadIdx.x   0  1  2  3  4  5  6     15      0    1    2    15
threadIdx.y   0  0  0  0  0  0  0      0      1    1    1     1
index:        0  1  2  3  4  5  6     15   1000 1001 1002  1015
```

Therefore the generated index pattern here shows a discontinuity between the 16th and 17th thread in the warp, and the access pattern does not fit your previously stated condition:

"threads within single warp access consecutive elements"

and we do not have coalesced access in this case (at least, for `float` quantities).

Comment: Thank you very much, Robert! Your explanation solves my confusion. I think that the problem tries to ask me about how to configure the matrix_multiplication kernel to avoid un-coalesces accesses when accessing global memory.  To do so, we need to make sure that dimBlock.x is dividable by 32 (size of a warp). Am I right?

Comment: yes, a block x dimension of 32 should give coalesced access